# Google Analytics Event Tracking in FV WordPress Flowplayer

Tags: plugins, google-analytics, wordpress

I am using FV WordPress Flowplayer in my wordpress site to display videos. I want to add google analytics event tracking in some of my videos. Any Ideas? I think this plugin do not support this. Any other plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the integration pretty easy. Flow Player supports an API for listening to like play, pause and finish. You can listen to those events using javascripot and fire an event when it happens.

eg:
    // get the first player
    var api = flowplayer();

```
api.bind("finish", function(e, api) {

   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'Video', 'play']);

});
```

More about flow player API:

http://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html

**UPDATE**

I found out that the flow player already have integration with Google Analytics.

http://flowplayer.org/docs/analytics.html